# fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedItemsVector(); causes Attempted to read or write protected memory error

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I am binding my gridview using following code in c# as

CollectionViewSource globalSource = App.Current.Resources["GlobalViewSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
globalSource.Source = fileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedItemsVector();

Here i declared collection view source in app.xaml because i need to use same source in other pages also.

It is frequent error when i navigate from one page to another page and error occurs in above lines.

Can you please guide how to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What error are you getting? Where exactly are you calling the above code when you navigate from one page to another? Does the problem go away if you use a different `CollectionViewSource` on each page?

Comment: I need to use same CollectionViewSource on both pages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved now..

Actually same source i was using for another page control. 
I have removed that source and its working fine now